# How to reset Bullet-at-a-time behavior in google slides

Tags: google-slides

I have a presentation that I have been told to use. When in presentation mode, each page builds one bullets at a time.

I want each page to show all bullets at once as soon as the page is shown.

I think I've found how change this behavior one bullet at a time, but that's going to take forever to change all of them.

Can I change this behavior in some global or "all at once" way?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I want to turn that off so that each page shows in its entirety immediately I go to the next page.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, about `Can I turn this off on in some way in a single operation?`, in this case, if your goal can be achieve by API and Slides service, will you use a script for it?

Comment: Same with Tanaike, I also cannot understand the same part of your question @TobyEggitt. I would just like to clarify if what you're asking is of the same scenario on this link: https://www.presentation-process.com/one-slide-per-bullet-.html but just in Google Slides platform? If not, please let us know what's your exact concern. Thank you.

Comment: The presentation as supplied insists on building one bullet at a time. I want the entire page to show at once. I hope to avoid setting every single slide manually, instead just making a global change to the document in a single command.